# How do I repair conda after a system crash?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I was running this command `conda install -c xonsh/channel/dev xonsh` when I got a blue screen (black on my macOS :D).
Now running it results in this output:

```
Solving environment: done

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: /Users/evar/anaconda

  added / updated specs:
    - xonsh


The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

    more-itertools:                     4.1.0-py35_0
    setproctitle:                       1.1.9-py35_0               xonsh/channel/dev
    xonsh:                              0.4.4.dev0-py35_gaa8b735   xonsh/channel/dev

The following packages will be UPDATED:

    _license:                           1.1-py36_1                                   --> 1.1-py35_1
    alabaster:                          0.7.10-py36h174008c_0                        --> 0.7.10-py35hb692fe1_0
    anaconda-client:                    1.6.11-py36_0                                --> 1.6.14-py35_0
    anaconda-navigator:                 1.7.0-py36_0                                 --> 1.8.2-py35_0
    anaconda-project:                   0.8.2-py36h9ee5d53_0                         --> 0.8.2-py35ha24014a_0
    appnope:                            0.1.0-py36hf537a9a_0                         --> 0.1.0-py35hd172556_0
    appscript:                          1.0.1-py36h9e71e49_1                         --> 1.0.1-py35hdfff33c_1
    asn1crypto:                         0.24.0-py36_0                                --> 0.24.0-py35_0
    astroid:                            1.6.1-py36_0                                 --> 1.6.2-py35_0
    astropy:                            3.0-py36h917ab60_1                           --> 3.0.1-py35h917ab60_1
    attrs:                              17.4.0-py36_0                                --> 17.4.0-py35_0
    babel:                              2.5.3-py36_0                                 --> 2.5.3-py35_0
    backports:                          1.0-py36ha3c1827_1                           --> 1.0-py35h2556c16_1
    backports.shutil_get_terminal_size: 1.0.0-py36hd7a2ee4_2                         --> 1.0.0-py35h40fcb1f_2
    beautifulsoup4:                     4.6.0-py36h72d3c9f_1                         --> 4.6.0-py35hb75f182_1
    bitarray:                           0.8.1-py36h1de35cc_1                         --> 0.8.1-py35h1de35cc_1
    blaze:                              0.11.3-py36h02e7a37_0                        --> 0.11.3-py35h385aa17_0
    bleach:                             2.1.3-py36_0                                 --> 2.1.3-py35_0
    bokeh:                              0.12.14-py36_0                               --> 0.12.14-py35_0
    boto:                               2.48.0-py36hdbc59ac_1                        --> 2.48.0-py35h10f7326_1
    bottleneck:                         1.2.1-py36hbd380ad_0                         --> 1.2.1-py35h969083f_0
    certifi:                            2018.1.18-py36_0                             --> 2018.1.18-py35_0
    cffi:                               1.11.5-py36h342bebf_0                        --> 1.11.5-py35h342bebf_0
    chardet:                            3.0.4-py36h96c241c_1                         --> 3.0.4-py35h16a84c2_1
    click:                              6.7-py36hec950be_0                           --> 6.7-py35hcc65ea6_0
    cloudpickle:                        0.5.2-py36_1                                 --> 0.5.2-py35_1
    clyent:                             1.2.2-py36hae3ad88_0                         --> 1.2.2-py35h63ae3d7_0
    colorama:                           0.3.9-py36hd29a30c_0                         --> 0.3.9-py35h1d66b2b_0
    conda:                              4.4.11-py36_0                                --> 4.5.0-py35_0
    contextlib2:                        0.5.5-py36hd66e5e7_0                         --> 0.5.5-py35hc2c67b4_0
    cryptography:                       2.1.4-py36h842514c_0                         --> 2.2.1-py35h1de35cc_0
    cycler:                             0.10.0-py36hfc81398_0                        --> 0.10.0-py35hb89929e_0
    cython:                             0.27.3-py36h6ecb376_0                        --> 0.28.1-py35h1de35cc_0
    cytoolz:                            0.9.0.1-py36h1de35cc_0                       --> 0.9.0.1-py35h1de35cc_0
    dask:                               0.17.1-py36_0                                --> 0.17.2-py35_0
    dask-core:                          0.17.1-py36_0                                --> 0.17.2-py35_0
    datashape:                          0.5.4-py36hfb22df8_0                         --> 0.5.4-py35hd065018_0
    decorator:                          4.2.1-py36_0                                 --> 4.2.1-py35_0
    distributed:                        1.21.2-py36_0                                --> 1.21.4-py35_0
    docutils:                           0.14-py36hbfde631_0                          --> 0.14-py35hb13dbd9_0
    entrypoints:                        0.2.3-py36hd81d71f_2                         --> 0.2.3-py35h837ec6f_2
    et_xmlfile:                         1.0.1-py36h1315bdc_0                         --> 1.0.1-py35h40eb147_0
    fastcache:                          1.0.2-py36h1de35cc_2                         --> 1.0.2-py35h1de35cc_2
    flask:                              0.12.2-py36h5658096_0                        --> 0.12.2-py35h7284a24_0
    flask-cors:                         3.0.3-py36h7387b97_0                         --> 3.0.3-py35h7e589ad_0
    gevent:                             1.2.2-py36ha70b9d6_0                         --> 1.2.2-py35h8412070_0
    gmpy2:                              2.0.8-py36hf9c35bd_2                         --> 2.0.8-py35h212fb8a_2
    greenlet:                           0.4.13-py36h1de35cc_0                        --> 0.4.13-py35h1de35cc_0
    h5py:                               2.7.1-py36h39cdac5_0                         --> 2.7.1-py35he1c7800_0
    heapdict:                           1.0.0-py36_2                                 --> 1.0.0-py35_2
    html5lib:                           1.0.1-py36h2f9c1c0_0                         --> 1.0.1-py35h2f9c1c0_0
    idna:                               2.6-py36h8628d0a_1                           --> 2.6-py35h01aacb0_1
    imageio:                            2.2.0-py36h5e01289_0                         --> 2.3.0-py35_0
    imagesize:                          1.0.0-py36_0                                 --> 1.0.0-py35_0
    ipykernel:                          4.8.2-py36_0                                 --> 4.8.2-py35_0
    ipython:                            6.2.1-py36h3dda519_1                         --> 6.2.1-py35h9470683_1
    ipython_genutils:                   0.2.0-py36h241746c_0                         --> 0.2.0-py35hf129286_0
    ipywidgets:                         7.1.2-py36_0                                 --> 7.1.2-py35_0
    isort:                              4.3.4-py36_0                                 --> 4.3.4-py35_0
    itsdangerous:                       0.24-py36h49fbb8d_1                          --> 0.24-py35hfbd69cd_1
    jdcal:                              1.3-py36h1986823_0                           --> 1.3-py35h9028778_0
    jedi:                               0.11.1-py36_0                                --> 0.11.1-py35_1
    jinja2:                             2.10-py36hd36f9c5_0                          --> 2.10-py35h6ff70ae_0
    jsonschema:                         2.6.0-py36hb385e00_0                         --> 2.6.0-py35h2dd9e4b_0
    jupyter:                            1.0.0-py36_4                                 --> 1.0.0-py35_4
    jupyter_client:                     5.2.2-py36_0                                 --> 5.2.3-py35_0
    jupyter_console:                    5.2.0-py36hccf5b1c_1                         --> 5.2.0-py35hd2aa692_1
    jupyter_core:                       4.4.0-py36h79cf704_0                         --> 4.4.0-py35h4ad9194_0
    kiwisolver:                         1.0.1-py36h792292d_0                         --> 1.0.1-py35h219a9d8_0
    lazy-object-proxy:                  1.3.1-py36h2fbbe47_0                         --> 1.3.1-py35h7293e74_0
    llvmlite:                           0.22.0-py36h35728e8_0                        --> 0.22.0-py35h4df07f0_0
    locket:                             0.2.0-py36hca03003_1                         --> 0.2.0-py35h58cf053_1
    lxml:                               4.1.1-py36hef8c89e_1                         --> 4.2.1-py35h7166777_0
    markupsafe:                         1.0-py36h3a1e703_1                           --> 1.0-py35h9ba0a7f_1
    matplotlib:                         2.2.0-py36hfa7797c_0                         --> 2.2.2-py35ha7267d0_0
    mccabe:                             0.6.1-py36hdaeb55d_0                         --> 0.6.1-py35h3f6a9a1_0
    mistune:                            0.8.3-py36_0                                 --> 0.8.3-py35_0
    mkl-service:                        1.1.2-py36h7ea6df4_4                         --> 1.1.2-py35h6a6947a_4
    mpmath:                             1.0.0-py36hf1b8295_2                         --> 1.0.0-py35he743aed_2
    msgpack-python:                     0.5.5-py36h04f5b5a_0                         --> 0.5.6-py35h04f5b5a_0
    multipledispatch:                   0.5.0-py36_0                                 --> 0.5.0-py35_0
    navigator-updater:                  0.1.0-py36h7aee5fb_0                         --> 0.1.0-py35hd04e0bf_0
    nbconvert:                          5.3.1-py36h810822e_0                         --> 5.3.1-py35h63fb950_0
    nbformat:                           4.4.0-py36h827af21_0                         --> 4.4.0-py35h41c2038_0
    networkx:                           2.1-py36_0                                   --> 2.1-py35_0
    nltk:                               3.2.5-py36h1190bce_0                         --> 3.2.5-py35h87b897b_0
    nose:                               1.3.7-py36h73fae2b_2                         --> 1.3.7-py35h9ce1e3a_2
    notebook:                           5.4.0-py36_0                                 --> 5.4.1-py35_0
    numba:                              0.37.0-np114py36h210bcc1_0                   --> 0.37.0-np114py35hc1fb402_0
    numexpr:                            2.6.4-py36habcfcfe_0                         --> 2.6.4-py35hcf51bc4_0
    numpy:                              1.14.1-py36ha726252_2                        --> 1.14.2-py35ha9ae307_0
    numpydoc:                           0.7.0-py36he54d08e_0                         --> 0.7.0-py35h296b98c_0
    odo:                                0.5.1-py36hc1af34a_0                         --> 0.5.1-py35h7f7a387_0
    olefile:                            0.45.1-py36_0                                --> 0.45.1-py35_0
    openpyxl:                           2.5.0-py36_0                                 --> 2.5.1-py35_0
    openssl:                            1.0.2n-hdbc3d79_0                            --> 1.0.2o-h26aff7b_0
    packaging:                          17.1-py36_0                                  --> 17.1-py35_0
    pandas:                             0.22.0-py36h0a44026_0                        --> 0.22.0-py35h0a44026_0
    pandocfilters:                      1.4.2-py36h3b0b094_1                         --> 1.4.2-py35hff87490_1
    parso:                              0.1.1-py36hc90e01c_0                         --> 0.1.1-py35hbda7c10_0
    partd:                              0.3.8-py36hf5c4cb8_0                         --> 0.3.8-py35h6fadee7_0
    path.py:                            11.0-py36_0                                  --> 11.0-py35_0
    pathlib2:                           2.3.0-py36h877a6d8_0                         --> 2.3.0-py35hba2ddec_0
    patsy:                              0.5.0-py36_0                                 --> 0.5.0-py35_0
    pep8:                               1.7.1-py36_0                                 --> 1.7.1-py35_0
    pexpect:                            4.4.0-py36_0                                 --> 4.4.0-py35_0
    pickleshare:                        0.7.4-py36hf512f8e_0                         --> 0.7.4-py35h9517181_0
    pillow:                             5.0.0-py36hfcce615_0                         --> 5.0.0-py35hfcce615_0
    pip:                                9.0.1-py36_5                                 --> 9.0.1-py35_5
    pluggy:                             0.6.0-py36hb1d0581_0                         --> 0.6.0-py35hf57b818_0
    ply:                                3.11-py36_0                                  --> 3.11-py35_0
    prompt_toolkit:                     1.0.15-py36haeda067_0                        --> 1.0.15-py35h93950c5_0
    psutil:                             5.4.3-py36h1de35cc_0                         --> 5.4.3-py35h1de35cc_0
    ptyprocess:                         0.5.2-py36he6521c3_0                         --> 0.5.2-py35hfc37984_0
    py:                                 1.5.2-py36ha69170d_0                         --> 1.5.3-py35_0
    pycodestyle:                        2.3.1-py36h83e8646_0                         --> 2.3.1-py35he0976b1_0
    pycosat:                            0.6.3-py36hee92d8f_0                         --> 0.6.3-py35h745f8c1_0
    pycparser:                          2.18-py36h724b2fc_1                          --> 2.18-py35hab820b0_1
    pycrypto:                           2.6.1-py36h1de35cc_7                         --> 2.6.1-py35h1de35cc_7
    pycurl:                             7.43.0.1-py36hdbc3d79_0                      --> 7.43.0.1-py35hdbc3d79_0
    pyflakes:                           1.6.0-py36hea45e83_0                         --> 1.6.0-py35hc517269_0
    pygments:                           2.2.0-py36h240cd3f_0                         --> 2.2.0-py35h392a662_0
    pylint:                             1.8.2-py36_0                                 --> 1.8.3-py35_0
    pyodbc:                             4.0.22-py36h0a44026_0                        --> 4.0.22-py35h0a44026_0
    pyopenssl:                          17.5.0-py36h51e4350_0                        --> 17.5.0-py35h4065cf8_0
    pyparsing:                          2.2.0-py36hb281f35_0                         --> 2.2.0-py35h31fab04_0
    pyqt:                               5.6.0-py36he5c6137_6                         --> 5.6.0-py35hbd126f6_6
    pysocks:                            1.6.8-py36_0                                 --> 1.6.8-py35_0
    pytables:                           3.4.2-py36hfbd7ab0_2                         --> 3.4.2-py35hda701c8_2
    pytest:                             3.4.2-py36_0                                 --> 3.5.0-py35_0
    pytest-arraydiff:                   0.2-py36_0                                   --> 0.2-py35_0
    pytest-astropy:                     0.2.1-py36_0                                 --> 0.2.1-py35_0
    pytest-doctestplus:                 0.1.2-py36_0                                 --> 0.1.2-py35_0
    pytest-openfiles:                   0.2.0-py36_0                                 --> 0.2.0-py35_0
    pytest-remotedata:                  0.2.0-py36_0                                 --> 0.2.0-py35_0
    python-dateutil:                    2.6.1-py36h86d2abb_1                         --> 2.7.2-py35_0
    python.app:                         2-py36h54569d5_7                             --> 2-py35he4d1c94_7
    pytz:                               2018.3-py36_0                                --> 2018.3-py35_0
    pywavelets:                         0.5.2-py36h2710a04_0                         --> 0.5.2-py35h9dc8fb8_0
    pyyaml:                             3.12-py36h2ba1e63_1                          --> 3.12-py35hf8cec8a_1
    pyzmq:                              17.0.0-py36h1de35cc_0                        --> 17.0.0-py35h1de35cc_0
    qtawesome:                          0.4.4-py36h468c6fb_0                         --> 0.4.4-py35h21e61ad_0
    qtconsole:                          4.3.1-py36hd96c0ff_0                         --> 4.3.1-py35hd6d667b_0
    qtpy:                               1.3.1-py36h16bb863_0                         --> 1.4.0-py35_0
    requests:                           2.18.4-py36h4516966_1                        --> 2.18.4-py35h0d65e6b_1
    rope:                               0.10.7-py36h68959ac_0                        --> 0.10.7-py35h27868a4_0
    ruamel_yaml:                        0.15.35-py36h1de35cc_1                       --> 0.15.35-py35h1de35cc_1
    scikit-image:                       0.13.1-py36h1de35cc_1                        --> 0.13.1-py35h1de35cc_1
    scikit-learn:                       0.19.1-py36hffbff8c_0                        --> 0.19.1-py35h2b554eb_0
    scipy:                              1.0.0-py36h1de22e9_0                         --> 1.0.0-py35h8b35106_0
    seaborn:                            0.8.1-py36h595ecd9_0                         --> 0.8.1-py35he0bbe96_0
    send2trash:                         1.5.0-py36_0                                 --> 1.5.0-py35_0
    setuptools:                         38.5.1-py36_0                                --> 38.5.1-py35_0
    simplegeneric:                      0.8.1-py36_2                                 --> 0.8.1-py35_2
    singledispatch:                     3.4.0.3-py36hf20db9d_0                       --> 3.4.0.3-py35h0acf360_0
    sip:                                4.18.1-py36h2824476_2                        --> 4.18.1-py35h79e1f92_2
    six:                                1.11.0-py36h0e22d5e_1                        --> 1.11.0-py35h39a4c60_1
    snowballstemmer:                    1.2.1-py36h6c7b616_0                         --> 1.2.1-py35hbb7be01_0
    sortedcollections:                  0.5.3-py36he9c3ed6_0                         --> 0.6.1-py35_0
    sortedcontainers:                   1.5.9-py36_0                                 --> 1.5.9-py35_0
    sphinx:                             1.7.1-py36_0                                 --> 1.7.2-py35_0
    sphinxcontrib:                      1.0-py36h9364dc8_1                           --> 1.0-py35h3eabf46_1
    sphinxcontrib-websupport:           1.0.1-py36h92f4a7a_1                         --> 1.0.1-py35hcb4ca16_1
    spyder:                             3.2.7-py36_0                                 --> 3.2.8-py35_0
    sqlalchemy:                         1.2.4-py36h1de35cc_0                         --> 1.2.5-py35h1de35cc_0
    statsmodels:                        0.8.0-py36h9c68fc9_0                         --> 0.8.0-py35ha7c9052_0
    sympy:                              1.1.1-py36h7f3cf04_0                         --> 1.1.1-py35he478fab_0
    tblib:                              1.3.2-py36hda67792_0                         --> 1.3.2-py35h1b9c5fd_0
    terminado:                          0.8.1-py36_1                                 --> 0.8.1-py35_1
    testpath:                           0.3.1-py36h625a49b_0                         --> 0.3.1-py35hf8009f4_0
    toolz:                              0.9.0-py36_0                                 --> 0.9.0-py35_0
    tornado:                            5.0-py36_0                                   --> 5.0-py35_0
    traitlets:                          4.3.2-py36h65bd3ce_0                         --> 4.3.2-py35hd3d1486_0
    typing:                             3.6.4-py36_0                                 --> 3.6.4-py35_0
    unicodecsv:                         0.14.1-py36he531d66_0                        --> 0.14.1-py35h2154ad0_0
    urllib3:                            1.22-py36h68b9469_0                          --> 1.22-py35he002d57_0
    webencodings:                       0.5.1-py36h3b9701d_1                         --> 0.5.1-py35hcf8ebf9_1
    werkzeug:                           0.14.1-py36_0                                --> 0.14.1-py35_0
    wheel:                              0.30.0-py36h5eb2c71_1                        --> 0.30.0-py35h5c0b906_1
    widgetsnbextension:                 3.1.4-py36_0                                 --> 3.1.4-py35_0
    wrapt:                              1.10.11-py36hc29e774_0                       --> 1.10.11-py35ha18cf31_0
    xlrd:                               1.1.0-py36h336f4a2_1                         --> 1.1.0-py35h892fcf7_1
    xlsxwriter:                         1.0.2-py36h3736301_0                         --> 1.0.2-py35h4d68a89_0
    xlwings:                            0.11.7-py36_0                                --> 0.11.7-py35_0
    xlwt:                               1.2.0-py36h5ad1178_0                         --> 1.2.0-py35hf70d7fa_0
    zict:                               0.1.3-py36h71da714_0                         --> 0.1.3-py35h1ae85d2_0

The following packages will be DOWNGRADED:

    anaconda:                           custom-py36ha4fed55_0                        --> custom-py35hd7b5ba2_0
    python:                             3.6.4-hc167b69_1                             --> 3.5.5-hc167b69_1
    wcwidth:                            0.1.7-py36h8c6ec74_0                         --> 0.1.5-py35_5               xonsh/channel/dev

Proceed ([y]/n)? y

Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: failed

SafetyError: The package for html5lib located at /Users/evar/anaconda/pkgs/html5lib-1.0.1-py35h2f9c1c0_0
appears to be corrupted. The path 'lib/python3.5/site-packages/html5lib/__pycache__/_tokenizer.cpython-35.pyc'
has a sha256 mismatch.
  reported sha256: 95475d9a871d7e07cb2b8af6d985068c5a1ceb9d593e5c21e42fa8019c7c14c0
  actual sha256: e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855

CondaVerificationError: The package for html5lib located at /Users/evar/anaconda/pkgs/html5lib-1.0.1-py35h2f9c1c0_0
appears to be corrupted. The path 'lib/python3.5/site-packages/html5lib/__pycache__/constants.cpython-35.pyc'
specified in the package manifest cannot be found.

CondaVerificationError: The package for html5lib located at /Users/evar/anaconda/pkgs/html5lib-1.0.1-py35h2f9c1c0_0
appears to be corrupted. The path 'lib/python3.5/site-packages/html5lib/__pycache__/html5parser.cpython-35.pyc'
specified in the package manifest cannot be found.

CondaVerificationError: The package for html5lib located at /Users/evar/anaconda/pkgs/html5lib-1.0.1-py35h2f9c1c0_0
appears to be corrupted. The path 'lib/python3.5/site-packages/html5lib/_tokenizer.py'
specified in the package manifest cannot be found.

CondaVerificationError: The package for html5lib located at /Users/evar/anaconda/pkgs/html5lib-1.0.1-py35h2f9c1c0_0
appears to be corrupted. The path 'lib/python3.5/site-packages/html5lib/constants.py'
specified in the package manifest cannot be found.

CondaVerificationError: The package for html5lib located at /Users/evar/anaconda/pkgs/html5lib-1.0.1-py35h2f9c1c0_0
appears to be corrupted. The path 'lib/python3.5/site-packages/html5lib/filters/__init__.py'
specified in the package manifest cannot be found.

CondaVerificationError: The package for html5lib located at /Users/evar/anaconda/pkgs/html5lib-1.0.1-py35h2f9c1c0_0
appears to be corrupted. The path 'lib/python3.5/site-packages/html5lib/html5parser.py'
specified in the package manifest cannot be found.

CondaVerificationError: The package for pyqt located at /Users/evar/anaconda/pkgs/pyqt-5.6.0-py35hbd126f6_6
appears to be corrupted. The path 'bin/pylupdate5'
specified in the package manifest cannot be found.

CondaVerificationError: The package for pyqt located at /Users/evar/anaconda/pkgs/pyqt-5.6.0-py35hbd126f6_6
appears to be corrupted. The path 'lib/python3.5/site-packages/PyQt5/QtBluetooth.so'
specified in the package manifest cannot be found.

CondaVerificationError: The package for pyqt located at /Users/evar/anaconda/pkgs/pyqt-5.6.0-py35hbd126f6_6
appears to be corrupted. The path 'lib/python3.5/site-packages/PyQt5/QtCore.pyi'
specified in the package manifest cannot be found.

CondaVerificationError: The package for pyqt located at /Users/evar/anaconda/pkgs/pyqt-5.6.0-py35hbd126f6_6
appears to be corrupted. The path 'lib/python3.5/site-packages/PyQt5/QtCore.so'
specified in the package manifest cannot be found.

CondaVerificationError: The package for pyqt located at /Users/evar/anaconda/pkgs/pyqt-5.6.0-py35hbd126f6_6
appears to be corrupted. The path 'lib/python3.5/site-packages/PyQt5/QtDesigner.so'
specified in the package manifest cannot be found.

CondaVerificationError: The package for pyqt located at /Users/evar/anaconda/pkgs/pyqt-5.6.0-py35hbd126f6_6
appears to be corrupted. The path 'lib/python3.5/site-packages/PyQt5/QtGui.pyi'
specified in the package manifest cannot be found.

CondaVerificationError: The package for pyqt located at /Users/evar/anaconda/pkgs/pyqt-5.6.0-py35hbd126f6_6
appears to be corrupted. The path 'lib/python3.5/site-packages/PyQt5/QtGui.so'
specified in the package manifest cannot be found.

CondaVerificationError: The package for pyqt located at /Users/evar/anaconda/pkgs/pyqt-5.6.0-py35hbd126f6_6
appears to be corrupted. The path 'lib/python3.5/site-packages/PyQt5/QtHelp.so'
specified in the package manifest cannot be found.

CondaVerificationError: The package for pyqt located at /Users/evar/anaconda/pkgs/pyqt-5.6.0-py35hbd126f6_6
appears to be corrupted. The path 'lib/python3.5/site-packages/PyQt5/QtMultimedia.so'
specified in the package manifest cannot be found.

CondaVerificationError: The package for pyqt located at /Users/evar/anaconda/pkgs/pyqt-5.6.0-py35hbd126f6_6
appears to be corrupted. The path 'lib/python3.5/site-packages/PyQt5/QtMultimediaWidgets.so'
specified in the package manifest cannot be found.

SafetyError: The package for pyqt located at /Users/evar/anaconda/pkgs/pyqt-5.6.0-py35hbd126f6_6
appears to be corrupted. The path 'lib/python3.5/site-packages/PyQt5/QtNetwork.pyi'
has a sha256 mismatch.
  reported sha256: 6d1d0e8dab63eb82e73de1d2e7346ee0584e3796537d5c1d4c015ec22a7da356
  actual sha256: e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855

CondaVerificationError: The package for pyqt located at /Users/evar/anaconda/pkgs/pyqt-5.6.0-py35hbd126f6_6
appears to be corrupted. The path 'lib/python3.5/site-packages/PyQt5/QtNetwork.so'
specified in the package manifest cannot be found.

CondaVerificationError: The package for pyqt located at /Users/evar/anaconda/pkgs/pyqt-5.6.0-py35hbd126f6_6
appears to be corrupted. The path 'lib/python3.5/site-packages/PyQt5/QtNfc.so'
specified in the package manifest cannot be found.

CondaVerificationError: The package for pyqt located at /Users/evar/anaconda/pkgs/pyqt-5.6.0-py35hbd126f6_6
appears to be corrupted. The path 'lib/python3.5/site-packages/PyQt5/QtOpenGL.so'
specified in the package manifest cannot be found.
...
```

I looked at https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/troubleshooting.html# but I didn't find anything about these errors or what to do in the case of a system crash.

Comment: See https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/66084/88005

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can try `conda clean --all`, but I'm not sure that will quite get it.  You can also remove the package cache wholesale (i.e. `rm -rf /Users/evar/anaconda/pkgs`), but that is extreme, and you'll end up with potentially wasted disk space in the future.

Best solution, right now, is to remove any offending packages in the package cache manually.  That is, scan through the list of errors, and find the offending packages.

```
rm -rf /Users/evar/anaconda/pkgs/html5lib-1.0.1-py35h2f9c1c0_0* \
       /Users/evar/anaconda/pkgs/pyqt-5.6.0-py35hbd126f6_6*
```