# installation error for gaussian splatting

Tags: python, json, anaconda, conda

I am encountering this error while installing and am not able to fix the issue.

`CondaVerificationError: The package for pytorch located at C:\Users\pinokio\bin\miniconda\pkgs\pytorch-1.12.1-py3.7_cuda11.6_cudnn8_0 appears to be corrupted. The path 'Lib/site-packages/caffe2/experiments/python/tt_pad_op_test.py' specified in the package manifest cannot be found.`

Comment: You need to delete the folder and associated tarball (`.conda` or `.tar.gz`) of `C:\Users\pinokio\bin\miniconda\pkgs\pytorch-1.12.1-py3.7_cuda11.6_cudnn8_0`. Then try reinstalling. Be aware that the default Conda configuration is not intended for users to hack on package code directly (i.e., the code in an environment directory). If you need to do this, then the environment should instead be created in copy-only mode so that edits in environments do not impact the package code globablly (i.e., use `CONDA_ALWAYS_COPY=1 conda create ...`).

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried reinstalling?

```
conda uninstall pytorch
pip uninstall torch
pip uninstall torch # run this command

conda install pytorch
```

Comment: That the pip uninstall line is present twice, is a typo?

Comment: I was not a typo. I think it would work the same if you type that one but i read that you need to run it twice.

Answer (score 0):

It states that the package has been corrupted, and the path specified in the package manifest cannot be found. That means that your IDE's system tried using the specified package above, but did not find it. Try setting the package manifest to a different path, or try reinstalling the package.

Try running this in your terminal (if you run on a Windows computer):
`python -m pip uninstall (package)`, `pip uninstall (package)`, `python -m pip install (package)`, `pip install (package)`

Comment: I uninstalled and reinstalled pytorch, but this error comes up again while installing. The path 'Lib/site-packages/caffe2/python/helpers/__pycache__/fc.cpython-37.pyc'
specified in the package manifest cannot be found.

Comment: @ElangkumaranS did you use the answer above or did you try mine? If you tried both, then try looking on Github or other websites for the problem.

Comment: Yeah I did use the code that you have given as well. No luck. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: @ElangkumaranS Does this post answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49545358/how-do-i-repair-conda-after-a-system-crash

Comment: @ElangkumaranS you run that in the terminal it is not code.

Comment: I am not quite understanding your suggestion. Sorry but I am a newbie, I am running an installation file for gaussian splatting and ending up with this in between while installing on pinokio. //CondaVerificationError: The package for pytorch located at C:\Users\pinokio\bin\miniconda\pkgs\pytorch-1.12.1-py3.7_cuda11.6_cudnn8_0
appears to be corrupted. The path 'Lib/site-packages/caffe2/experiments/python/tt_pad_op_test.py'
specified in the package manifest cannot be found.

Comment: @ElangkumaranS did you try this yet https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49545358/how-do-i-repair-conda-after-a-system-crash